# How to defiine class variable not importing package with it?

Tags: actionscript-3

for example is it possible to do somehing like `public var socket:flash.net.Socket = new flash.net.Socket();`?

Comment: The important question, as always, is "What are you trying to do?". There are ways to partition your code and decouple it from other modules, but you'll have to provide a bit more background info.

Comment: You can do - You will need to use it when within the same class you will use 2 classes that has the same name e.g. you already imported `com.example.net.Socket` then to identify `flash.net.Socket` you will use full package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you will still get a class undefined compiler error if you don't import `flash.net.Socket`

Comment: It's worth noting that if there are two `Socket` classes imported, you _must_ use the full package path as described in the question.